# PulseAudio Modules are not properly configured when started on systemd or xsession, but works fine when started from terminal

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, xfce, pulseaudio, x-server

I'm trying to create some virtual source so that I can virtually have a microphone that is acceptable on all application that cannot directly grab the ".monitor" from my virtual sink.

Basically here is what I'm planning to create :

```
For System Audio recording :
Any Application Audio -> PulseEffects(apps) -> A_SINK -> alsa-card......

A virtual mic so I can pass an output as a input :
FFMPEG -> MIC_IN -> MIC_OUT

Combined 
A_SINK ==========\
                  |=> Mixed -> Mixed_OUT
MIC_OUT =========/
```

So far so good, after some testing this is what I came up with :

```
For System Audio recording :
Application -> module-null-sink("TIRTAGT_SINK") -> module-loopback("alsa_output.pci.analog-stereo")



For virtual mic :
FFMPEG -> module-null-sink("TIRTAGT_MIC_IN") -> module-remap-source(master="TIRTAGT_MIC_IN.monitor", source_name="TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT")



For Combined Mic and System Audio :
module-loopback(source="TIRTAGT_SINK.monitor") =====\
                                                     |==> module-null-sink("TIRTAGT_Mixed")
module-loopback(source="TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT") ==========/                  ||
                                                                       \/
module-remap-source(master="TIRTAGT_Mixed.monitor" source_name="TIRTAGT_Mixed_OUT")
```

Anything works perfectly fine, so I then modify the `/home/matthewtirta/.config/pulse/default.pa` to add this line at the end of file :

```
### Import addon for additional configuration
.nofail
.include /home/matthewtirta/.config/pulse/presets
```

alongside the respective commands that I put into the `/home/matthewtirta/.config/pulse/presets` directory :

- For System Audio recording (00-TIRTAGT_SINK.pa) :

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name='TIRTAGT_SINK' sink_properties=device.description='TIRTAGT_SINK'

load-module module-loopback source="TIRTAGT_SINK.monitor" sink="alsa_output.pci-0000_05_00.6.analog-stereo" latency_msec=25

set-default-sink TIRTAGT_SINK
```

- For Virtual Mic :

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name="TIRTAGT_MIC_IN" sink_properties=device.description='TIRTAGT_MIC_IN'

load-module module-remap-source master="TIRTAGT_MIC_IN.monitor" source_name="TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT" source_properties=device.description='TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT'

set-default-source TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT
```

- For Combined Mic and System Audio (02-TIRTAGT_Mixed.pa) :

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name="TIRTAGT_Mixed" sink_properties=device.description='TIRTAGT_Mixed'

load-module module-loopback source="TIRTAGT_SINK.monitor" sink="TIRTAGT_Mixed" latency_msec=25
load-module module-loopback source="TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT" sink="TIRTAGT_Mixed" latency_msec=25

load-module module-remap-source master="TIRTAGT_Mixed.monitor" source_name="TIRTAGT_Mixed_OUT" source_properties=device.description='TIRTAGT_Mixed_OUT'
```

For testing, I then stop the pulseaudio server by running `pulseaudio -k` as normal user.
At which, the pulseaudio stops and was getting restarted back by systemd that manages `pulseaudio.socket`, I then run `pavucontrol` and this is the output :

[image: Pavucontrol Playback tab]

[image: Pavucontrol Recording tab]

[image: Pavucontrol Output Devices]

[image: Pavucontrol Input Devices]

They doesn't seem correct as what are configured by the load-module commands.

However I was just too interested to see the result, so I started testing anyway even if the pavucontrol shows the loopback and remap is somewhat not on what they should be pointed to.

The experience was a big dissapointment, the virtual microphone output (TIRTAGT_MIC_OUT) is now hearable on my speakers so that mean it somehow was looped/redirected into TIRTAGT_SINK in some way.... and then I take a second look on `pavucontrol`, looks like it is indeed redirected to TIRTAGT_SINK :

[image: Why is the mic are going to speakers ?]

So I was curious to try an another restart `pulseaudio -k`, at which the systemd instantly starts up pulseaudio server again.

Unfortunately same result.

So this time..... I tried to disable the systemd automatic load by using `systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket pulseaudio.service`. Pulseaudio seems to be already stop running.   However just to make sure it is not running, I run another `pulseaudio -k`, and then I start it up manually `pulseaudio -D`.

Pulseaudio is now running again, and here's what `pavucontrol` shows me :
[image]

[image]

**2 tabs are left out due to the maximum 8 links for people with less than 10 reputation, however it's exactly the same as the one that is on systemd scenario*

The loopbacks and remap looks correct to me, so then I decided to give it another test, it performs just what I expected them to be. Now I can record my desktop audio while I'm also able to run FFMPEG and points it into the `TIRTAGT_MIC_IN` sink.

The screen recorder captures on `TIRTAGT_Mixed_OUT`, anything works fine !

So I think, let's just keep the systemd disabled and just put `pulseaudio -D &` to my `~/.xsession` file so pulseaudio is started on Session Login.

I then shutdown and start up my machine again, pulseaudio is online by looking at the xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin on the top panel, so then I started testing again !

To my surprise, anything is now messed up, exactly like what it did when systemd started the pulseaudio rather than me on terminal.

I'm not sure what's happening here, any help is appreciated !

Well I could actually type the `pulseaudio -D &` command every time my session starts, but I would prefer not to type it manually if that was really possible.